# Windows PHP extension only detected in Administrator mode

Tags: php, windows, php-extension, administrator, dbase

Info: Operating system: Win10, php 5.6.31

I added `dbase.dll` to my PHP extension dir and enabled it in `php.ini`.

When I open Cmd and run `php -i | find "dbase"` it is NOT found.

**Cmd output**

[image: Cmd output]

When I do exactly the same, but when Cmd run as Administrator, it works...

**Cmd output as Administrator**

[image: Cmd output as Administrator]

In IIS, when I do `phpinfo()` it's also there.

**IIS phpinfo**

[image: IIS phpinfo]

Same story with powershell, git bash, ...
Only works when run as Administrator. Does anyone have any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: is your php extension on d drive?

Comment: no, it's on the c drive